# WP push files to device over company app

Tags: windows-phone

With a company App configured on a Windows phone there is the posibiltiy to push the installation of an App. When the user starts the pushed App some configuration data must be introduced. I would like to save the user this step but I still don't know how. Isn't it possible to push files over the company App/Exchange, as it is on a Windows machine? So I could read the configuration out of this file.

Answer (score 0):

your use case does raise many questions (probably just terminology)

The only way to push an APP to a device is through the Windows Phone store or website.

If you want to push configuration to a device for an app then the app must be run at least once to enable that ability and you could then use a background task to periodically check for new configuration and download it.

The other thing you can investigate is push notifications but they are not really meant for pushing data, you can sent simple objects or data to the device as a raw push but the app must be running first.

The most common way to achieve what you describe is to have the app load config at launch, locally first and then update it from a web call (if web is available, as these are mobile devices you can not guarantee connectivity).  We do something very similar with AdRotator where we try to download config at start and if that fails use a locally cached version.

Answer (score 0):

As of WP 8.0 there isn't the possibility to push Apps or Files through the company App.